# What happens to traefik if the Kubernetes masters go down?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, reliability, traefik-ingress

I have a query, What happens to traefik if Kubernetes goes down? Will it keep working or will it crash/stop serving traffic?

Currently, I am using EKS for Kubernetes, with ALB ingress controller. My understanding is that, if Kubernetes master goes down, there won't be any upscaling-downscaling of PODs, no new deployments. But the existing applications deployed will at least keep serving traffic, as ALB is in place, nodes are there with PODs present and application is running.

But in case of traefik, traefik uses Kubernetes ingress resource to check for routing rules, and if Kubernetes itself is down, I don't think, traefik will get any response/data. In which case, it will either crash or clear its own config or it keeps serving traffic based on the last config it has stored. I am not sure about what happens to traefik if Kubernetes goes down.

Correct me if I am missing something, or I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as Traefik keeps running, it will be fine. But if it crashed and was restarted, it would be unable to load the endpoints API as you noted. Fortunately that is exceedingly rare.